# How to sort tableau chart by measure values?

Tags: tableau-desktop

Length of every horizontal bar of this chart determined by different column of data source. Only sort option that i found is by measure names, however i need to order the chart by measure values. How can i do that?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SjhV.png)

I tried sorting measure names without result. Pivoting table when connecting to data source is not an option, but if there is some way to do it after, that would probably be helpful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.